# Referencing cells within the Sumproduct function in Excel

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I 've got a formula that needs to be copied horizontally while the references shift up one spot with each spot I shift to the right. The formula is straightforward:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(AY34:AY44,D34:D44)/SUM(D34:D44),1)
```

As I shift to the right the formula shifts as follows:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(AZ33:AY43,E33:E43)/SUM(E33:E43),1)
```

The pattern continues. The column reference takes care of itself, but the row reference needs an n-1 adjustment.

I thought I could use index or indirect nested within the sumproduct function by creating a list of reference cells:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("A1"):AY43,E33:E43)/SUM(E33:E43),1) where the contents of cell A1 is "AZ33".
```

Excel does not seem to see INDIRECT("A1") as AZ33 though if I put that function by itself in a cell it does return the desired value.

I figure my syntax is wrong, or there is a better function to use. I tried INDEX() in place of INDIRECT() but excel doesn't see that either.

Can anyone explain this one to me like I am 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's establish a way to create a number that decreases when the formula is dragged to the right, starting with 34:

```
=ROW(A34)-COLUMN(A1)+1
```

Use this approach in an INDEX() function to reference a cell in that row in column A:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A34)-COLUMN(A1)+1)
```

That takes care of the start of the range you want to feed to Sumproduct. You can then extend the range returned by the Index() with the range operator `:` and hard wire the end of the range, say `$A$43` and use that inside the Sumproduct()

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A34)-COLUMN(A1)+1):$A$43)
```

In my example, I have anchored column A with $ signs to be absolute references, but just because I was too lazy to add more data to my test file. See in the screenshot how the formula in column J is now referencing E1, i.e. a relative column reference works, too.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I am very grateful! I will get a chance to test this out and adapt it to my workbook in a few hours. I will update this post then. Thank you!

Comment: I believe I can adopt your strategy to my project. Thanks again for your help.